# Show multiple keys inside one <kbd> tag

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I have a key sequence I want to display in github. Let's just say it's the Konami code.
So, I want the result to be <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

The way I've done this is by using some *extremely long* code:

```html
<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
```

Is there another way to do this without tons of `<kbd>`'s and `</kbd>`'s?

Answer (score 2):

Not really: as [shown here](https://github.com/shionit/til/wiki/GitHub-flavored-markdown-tricks), using only one `kbd` would only include everything, without any separation:

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + L</kbd>

So unless you can add separators inside *one* kbd sequence, you would need all those kbds you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm asking for - are there any seperators?

Comment: @The-Anonymous No separator that I know of. (that would render each symbol in its own key)